# File Server for backing up - Virtualize or buy another data server

Tags: windows, hard-drive, file-management

I have read there is not reason not to virtualize file server. We are on short budget. For future, doesn't it seem to be more logical to have one multi purpose virtualized server for DNS emails domain etc. and a data server for all backups of our employees? How exactly are backups separated from other content like OS, system files etc? Should we buy one server with a lot of HDD slots? We also want mirroring - RAID 1. What if one HDD exceeds the free space of one HDD? Windows server will be our primary OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No problem in itself to virtualise a file server, but backups should probably be kept as separate as possible. A separate physical server is better than backups on the same machine. A backup to some remote location (like a cloud service) is better still. Of course one doesn’t have to rule out the other, you can backup your file server remotely too.

RAID is a good idea, certainly if that’s the only backup server you have. In a mirrored RAID, the disks should be equal size, all across or at the very least in pairs, so that both sides of the mirror have the same disk space available.